# Quartz Scheduler - Second Job Not Executing

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to create two jobs that will execute daily. For some reason, only the first job is executing.  No exception is thrown. Any idea why this might be the case? Here's my code:

```
      SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();

          Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();

          sched.start();


        JobDetail sysJob = newJob(SysParseJob.class).withIdentity("sysJob").build();

        Trigger sysTrigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("sysTrigger")
                .forJob("sysJob")
                .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(0, 5)) // execute job daily at 12:05
                .build();

        sched.scheduleJob(sysJob, sysTrigger);


        JobDetail histJob = newJob(HistParseJob.class).withIdentity("histJob").build();

        Trigger histTrigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("histTrigger")
                .forJob("histJob")
                .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(0, 1)) // execute job daily at 12:01
                .build();

        sched.scheduleJob(histJob, histTrigger);
```

Comment: Enable quartz logging name="org.quartz" level="INFO" to see if your job is getting picked. If youa are using database as a job store you can the QRTZ tables also

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there might be some error in your trigger building. Check if this solves your purpose

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException,
            ParseException {
        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
        sched.start();

        JobDetail sysJob = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob1.class)
                .withIdentity(new JobKey("sysJob")).build();

        Trigger sysTrigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(new TriggerKey("sysTrigger"))
                .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(0, 51))
                .startNow()
                .build();
        sched.scheduleJob(sysJob, sysTrigger);

        JobDetail histJob = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob2.class)
                .withIdentity(new JobKey("histJob ")).build();

        Trigger sysTrigger2 = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(new TriggerKey("sysTrigger2"))
                .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(0, 52))
                .startNow()
                .build();
        sched.scheduleJob(histJob, sysTrigger2);
    }

    private static CronScheduleBuilder dailyAtHourAndMinute(int hour,int minute){
        return CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(hour, minute);
    }
```